# Equivalent points in the Projective Space $P^1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $P^1=\Bbb C \cup \infty$ be the projective space, for $1\le i \le k_1$ and $1\le j\le k_2$ and $p_i\ne q_j$ be different points in $P^1$. We say that$$\sum_{i=1}^{k_1}r_i p_i$$and $$\sum_{j=1}^{k_2}s_jq_j$$are equivalent if there exist a meromorphic function $f$ on $P^1$ such that $f$ has zeros at each $p_i$ of order $r_i$ and has poles at each $q_j$ of order $s_j$ where $r_i,s_j >0$, I'm trying to show that the two sums are equivalent if and only if$$\sum_{i=1}^{k_1}r_i=\sum_{j=1}^{k_2}s_j.$$ We know the following : the linear space of all meromorphic functions on $P^1$ with poles at $q_j$ of order at least $s_j$, and holomorphic elsewhere, denoted by $L(q_j)$, has dimension $\sum_{j=1}^{k_2}s_j+1$, and if $f$ has a zero of order $r$ at $p$, then $1/f$ has a pole of order $r$ at $p$. So I tried to prove that the dimension of $L(p_i)$ and the dimension of $L(q_j)$ are the same to prove the "if" direction, but I'm stuck. 
 Can you help please. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the argument principle to prove the condition is necessary, and bare-hands construction of a function to prove sufficiency.

Comment: what are the argument principle and the bare - hands construction ??

Comment: By bare-hands construction, I meant that you should write down the function explicitly. The Argument Principle is a standard theorem in complex analysis, using the Residue Theorem to count zeroes and poles.